# Update Controlled component when props changed from parent

Tags: reactjs

i have a question about what can be the best practice to update a controlled input with a props comming from its parent.

I have a component InputArea that contains lot of controlled input. In the construct of each input, i have a state initialized with a props from parent (value). But in my first input, i have an autosuggest component that fill every value of all input (firstname, lastname, date, email, phone etc).
So, my first component trigger an action to set the new state of InputArea with all values comming down from autosuggest.
So, all my input are re-rendered but nothing change (ok, i got this, we dont call the constructor, so the state of the input is not changed).

So, i tried to do this in componentDidUpdate with prevProps (but eslint said me i'm a looser). OK, i tried to set a key props for my input with key={value}. It works but bad, it unmount & mount my input. I saw derivated state or memoized, but it seems a bit "hard & dangerous" for a so simple feature.

I want to be ok with react 17 lifecycle to dont change it in 6 month, so i wont use componentWillUpdate or something else unsafe. As i love best practices, i search a lot on web but i'm not pretty sure about what i should do !

Does someone have an idea ?

Thx all ! =D

Comment: It's fine to check if `this.props.myProp !== prevProps.myProp` in `componentDidUpdate` and update your state if you need to. This will cause an extra re-render, but is fine in the majority of cases.

Comment: Yea, i saw react said it was not bad if we call it immediatly with a condition, but i see getDerivatedStateFromProps is done ONLY for this type of problems... So, why not use it ? It's written "not safe" or "you dont need that", but hey facebook, you've lost me xD

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called on every render, and you can't check if the prop you are actually interested in changed, like you can with `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: OK, so thx ! i will use it =D